# Where is Selenium IDE in Chrome's developer tools?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, ide

I just added the Selenium IDE to Chrome from the web store here -- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd .  However, when I fire up my developer tools, I don't see the IDE anywhere in the panel ...

[image]

How do I access the SElenium IDE In Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a small "Se" icon in the top right corner.  If not https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/getting-started/ has a couple of tips.  Entering chrome://extensions will confirm that it is installed.